# How to sum two matrix in a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to define some methods to a class Matrix that receives the number of rows and the number of columns, a list or a code as arguments.
I have to do:

```py
import numpy as np

class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, rows = 0, columns =0, data=None, code =''):
        if data is None:
            data = []
        self.code = ''
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.data = data
        self.code = code
        self.matrix = [[]]
        assert self.columns != 0 and self.rows != 0
        if code == 'z':
            self.matrix = np.zeros([self.rows, self.columns], int)
        elif code == 'u':
            self.matrix = np.ones([self.rows, self.columns], int)
        elif code == 'i':
            self.matrix = np.identity(self.rows, int)
        else:
            if code == '' and len(self.data) != 0:
                self.matrix = np.reshape(self.data, (-1, self.columns))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Matrix: {self.matrix}'

    def get_matrix(self):
        return self.matrix

    def sumM(self,m1):
        k = self.get_matrix()
        m1.get_matrix()
        print(k)
        print(m1.get_matrix())
        assert (self.rows == m1.rows)
        m3 = np.zeros([self.rows, self.rows])
        print(m3.shape)
        for i in range(m3.shape[0]):  
            for j in range(m3.shape[1]):  
                output = m1[i, j] + k[i, j]
            print(output)
        return m3
```

Although, when I'm call the sumM method, python retrieves the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/sandr/PycharmProjects/Trabalho 2/teste2.py", line 41, in sumM
    output = m1[i, j] + k[i, j]
TypeError: 'Matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's because your `Matrix` class doesn't have a `__getitem__` method. More pertinent though,  why are you creating your own class when `numpy` already does all this for you? Is this for practice?

Comment: You don't assign this to anything: `m1.get_matrix()`

Comment: @blorgon yes, it is for practice!

Comment: You need to implement the `__getitem__` method, but also I'd strongly recommend trying to implement your own `Vector` class first. There are quite a number of issues with your current implementation, and even implementing `__getitem__` isn't going to fix everything that's wrong.

Comment: A `Vector` would be an easier place to start. Implement the `__add__`, `__neg__`, and `__sub__`, methods to get a feel for how classes work in Python. Then move on to a `Matrix` class, which is a little bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def sumM(self,m1):
    k = self.get_matrix()
    k1 = m1.get_matrix()
    assert (self.rows == m1.rows)
    m3 = np.zeros([self.rows, self.rows])
    for i in range(m3.shape[0]):
        for j in range(m3.shape[1]):
            m3[i][j] = k1[i][j] + k[i][j]
    return m3
```

Comment: No problem. Also fix your __str__ method to: return f'Matrix:\n{self.matrix}'

Comment: thanks a lot! All of this is for a academic work and we cannot use numpy methods. I'm having difficulties to calculte an inverse of a matrix nxn.